# SQL query returns duplicates from AS/400 Server

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

If I just query on the main table OEINDLID, I will get only half the rows.

even  doing this query /400 is returning duplicates, how can I resolve this?

```
SELECT T01.IDORD#, T01.IDDOCD, T01.IDPRT#, T01.IDSHP#, T01.IDNTU$,
       (IDNTU$*(IDSHP#)) AS LINTOT, T02.IAPTWT, T02.IARCC3, T03.MHSTAT, T03.MHZONR,
       T03.MHSHIN, T01.IDORDT, T01.IDHCD3
FROM ASTDTA.OEINDLID T01 INNER JOIN
     ASTDTA.ICPRTMIA T02 
     ON T01.IDPRT# = T02.IAPRT# INNER JOIN
     astdta.MFHHMHPK T03
     ON T01.IDORD# = T03.MHORDP
WHERE  IDHCD3 in ('MDL','TRP')
```

The data required is this:

```
 322.05000000     04662926     RTR   US-LUCU810                   19.00          16.950000   
    .00000000     04662926     RTR   ENUSLUCU810                  19.00            .000000   
    .00000000     04662926     RTR   EXTRA CHAR CHG                1.00            .000000   
 284.05000000     04662926     RTR   US-LUCU79                    19.00          14.950000   
    .00000000     04662926     RTR   ENUSLUCU79                   19.00            .000000   
   4.75000000     04662926     RTR   EXTRA CHAR CHG               19.00            .250000   
  47.50000000-    04662926     RTR   DISCLU                       19.00           2.500000-  
  28.50000000-    04662926     RTR   DISCLU                       19.00           1.500000-  
 454.75000000-    04662926     RTR   DISCEN                        1.00         454.750000-  
  49.90000000     04662926     RTR   FRTTRP                        1.00          49.900000   
 297.50000000     04662926     RTR   US-DGBB1                    250.00           1.190000   
 162.50000000     04662926     RTR   CRDGBOX                     250.00            .650000   
 125.00000000     04662926     RTR   ENGDGT                      250.00            .500000   
 175.00000000     04662926     RTR   EXTRA CHAR CHG            1,750.00            .100000   
 297.50000000     04662926     RTR   US-DGBB1                    250.00           1.190000   
 162.50000000     04662926     RTR   CRDGBOX                     250.00            .650000   
 125.00000000     04662926     RTR   ENGDGT                      250.00            .500000   
 275.00000000     04662926     RTR   EXTRA CHAR CHG    2,750.00            .100000                            


  50.00000000-    04662926     RTR   DISCMD                      500.00            .100000-  
  50.00000000-    04662926     RTR   DISCMD                      500.00            .100000-  
 622.50000000     04662926     RTR   US-CM08RG                   250.00           2.490000   
 100.00000000     04662926     RTR   RIWRWB                      250.00            .400000   
 125.00000000     04662926     RTR   ENMD24BLK                   250.00            .500000   
    .00000000     04662926     RTR   EXENGMD                       1.00            .000000   
  75.00000000-    04662926     RTR   DISCMD                      250.00            .300000-  
 135.30000000     04662926     RTR   FRTMDL                        1.00         135.300000
```

but when we add in the joins where we want the part# data (weight etc) and then the shipping data
we get this:

```
 04662926    20,140,116   CRDGBOX                     250.00            .650000                       162.50000000          .02000
 04662926    20,140,116   CRDGBOX                     250.00            .650000                       162.50000000          .02000
 04662926    20,140,116   CRDGBOX                     250.00            .650000                       162.50000000          .02000
 04662926    20,140,116   CRDGBOX                     250.00            .650000                       162.50000000          .02000
```

you can see in the exampleof the part CRDGBOX we have 2 above but 4 here once we have the inner joins.

Comment: Your joins are presumably creating duplicate rows.  You don't provide enough information to say anything more.

Comment: what is needed to tell you?

Comment: Provide sample data, results, and desired results.

Comment: the first table has the order info. the second is the part# info there we only want to get the part weight and cat code.and then on the 3rd table, we get some shipping data. It seems that these joins are taking an extra row but why

Comment: Probably become some order along the way has the same part listed twice.  Or the order itself was shipped in multiple parts.

Comment: ok but what can be done to this? We would only want one link per order to the other 2

Answer (score 0):

Try SELECT DISTINCT:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
               MHORDP, MHSTAT, MHZONR, MHSHIN
             FROM ASTDTA.MFHHMHPK) AS T03 ON T01.IDORD# = T03.MHORDP
```